# Hibernate HQL issue after migration from Jboss4.2 to Jboss7.2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jboss7.x, jboss-4.2.x

Recently We have migrated from Jboss4.2 to Jboss 7.2. Exact same HQL query is running fine for Jboss4.2. But in Jboss7.2 HQL query is not running properly in Jboss7.2, it's giving error that I have mentioned below:

```
no persistent classes found for query class: SELECT distinct
pf.projectFormId FROM com.gsk.rd.craw.model.ProjectForm pf   left join
pf.contacts c WHERE pf.createdBy=:mudid OR pf.modifiedBy=:mudid OR
c.mudid=:mudid 

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named
parameter



18:33:04,338 TRACE [org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache]
(http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Unable to locate HQL query plan in cache;
generating (SELECT distinct pf.projectFormId FROM
com.gsk.rd.craw.model.ProjectForm pf   left join pf.contacts c WHERE
pf.createdBy=:mudid OR pf.modifiedBy=:mudid OR c.mudid=:mudid )
18:33:04,338 TRACE [org.jboss.modules] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1)
Finding class com.gsk.rd.craw.model.ProjectForm from Module
"deployment.craw.ear:main" from Service Module Loader 18:33:04,338
TRACE [org.jboss.modules] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Finding local class
com.gsk.rd.craw.model.ProjectForm from Module
"deployment.craw.ear.craw_jar.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
18:33:04,338 TRACE [org.jboss.modules] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Found
previously loaded class com.gsk.rd.craw.model.ProjectForm from Module
"deployment.craw.ear.craw_jar.jar:main" from Service Module Loader
18:33:04,339 WARN  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.QuerySplitter]
(http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) HHH000183: no persistent classes found for
query class: SELECT distinct pf.projectFormId FROM
com.gsk.rd.craw.model.ProjectForm pf   left join pf.contacts c WHERE
pf.createdBy=:mudid OR pf.modifiedBy=:mudid OR c.mudid=:mudid 
18:33:04,339 INFO  [stdout] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1)
0000000000000000000000000000000003333333333333333333333333


18:33:04,346 TRACE [org.jboss.modules] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1)
Finding local class org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl from
Module "org.hibernate:main" from local module loader @3c20902c
(finder: local module finder @7dd9578a (roots:
D:\CRAW_JBOSS7.2\aries-sandbox\jboss-as-7.2.0.Final\modules,D:\CRAW_JBOSS7.2\aries-sandbox\jboss-as-7.2.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))
18:33:04,346 TRACE [org.jboss.modules] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1) Found
previously loaded class org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl from
Module "org.hibernate:main" from local module loader @3c20902c
(finder: local module finder @7dd9578a (roots:
D:\CRAW_JBOSS7.2\aries-sandbox\jboss-as-7.2.0.Final\modules,D:\CRAW_JBOSS7.2\aries-sandbox\jboss-as-7.2.0.Final\modules\system\layers\base))
18:33:04,341 SEVERE [facelets.viewhandler] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1)
Error Rendering View[/ProjectFormCatalog.jsp]:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named
parameter [mudid]
```

We have upgraded:

- Java from jdk1.5 to jdk1.7,
- Hibernate 3 to Hibernate 4,
- JPA 1  we have used for both version,
- EJB 3 we have used for both version

Comment: this should be an issue with the maintainers, not the stack community. Additionally, you have not provided any real code to help anyone solve the issue.

Comment: I please find the code **below**       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private List<Long> getProjectFormIdsByContact() {
        String sql = "SELECT distinct pf.projectFormId " + "FROM com.gsk.rd.craw.model.ProjectForm pf " + "  left join pf.contacts c "
                + "WHERE pf.createdBy=:mudid " + "OR pf.modifiedBy=:mudid " + "OR c.mudid=:mudid ";
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sql);
        
        query.setParameter("mudid", mudId);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

Comment: This same query is working fine for Jboss 4.2.

Answer (score 0):

Check your HQL query syntax whether mudid is really a database column name/hibernate Entity property name  available or not?

Comment: Yea same query , its Running fine in Jboss 4.2 but i am geeting error in Jboss 7.2 I have mentioned query below.         String sql = "SELECT distinct pf.projectFormId " + "FROM com.gsk.rd.craw.model.ProjectForm pf " + "  left join pf.contacts c "
                + "WHERE pf.createdBy=:mudid " + "OR pf.modifiedBy=:mudid " + "OR c.mudid=:mudid ";
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(sql);

Comment: I am using the same query for both Jboss version. I have mentioned the query above. Dont know what is the issue , same query running fine in Jboss 4.2. Please help me. I am new in Jboss environment.

Comment: There are a lot of difference between Jboss 4.2 to JBoss 7.2.  Also Hibernate and JPA versions. Paste the hibernate entity class "com.gsk.rd.craw.model.ProjectForm.java" to review?

Comment: **Thanks for your HELP** PLEASE find the hibernate entity class "com.gsk.rd.craw.model.ProjectForm.java" BELOW **

Comment: "com.gsk.rd.craw.model.ProjectForm.java" hibernate entity class  have more than 900 lines so, unable to paste it here.

Comment: Hi, I can't find the source code of "com.gsk.rd.craw.model.ProjectForm.java" just want see the skeleton of the Entity class. Copy starting from class name and its properties and paste it here.

Comment: I am pasting it here in part wise. (PART 1)

Comment: package com.gsk.rd.craw.model;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

Comment: import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import org.apache.commons.lang.ObjectUtils;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

Comment: import org.hibernate.annotations.IndexColumn;
import org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet;
import org.hibernate.validator.Length;
import org.hibernate.validator.NotNull;

import com.gsk.rd.aries.common.security.SecurityUtil;
import com.gsk.rd.craw.workflow.Workflow;
import com.gsk.rd.craw.workflow.WorkflowState;
import com.gsk.rd.craw.workflow.Workflowable;


/**
 * ProjectForm generated by hbm2java
 */

Comment: @Entity(name="com.gsk.rd.craw.model.ProjectForm")
@Table(name = "PROJECT_FORM")
@NamedQueries(value = {
  @NamedQuery(name = "findProjectFormBySow", query = "from com.gsk.rd.craw.model.ProjectForm p where p.sow in(:sow)")
})
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class ProjectForm extends ModifiableEntity implements Workflowable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private long projectFormId;
    private ServiceType serviceType;
    private Sow sow;
    private Cro cro;

Comment: private String lnbWorkRequestId;
    private Date lnbWorkRequestVer;
    private Integer lnbWorkRequestVersion = Integer.valueOf(1);
    private Date submittedDate;
    private String submittedBy;
    private String submitterEmail;
    private String submitterPhone;
    private OrgUnit businessOrgUnit;
    private OrgUnit organizationOrgUnit;
    private OrgUnit departmentOrgUnit;
    private String site;
    private Long projectId;
    private String projectName;

Comment: private String projectDiseaseArea;
    private Date requestedDeliveryDate;
    private Date estimatedDeliveryDate;
    private Date actualDeliveryDate;
    private WorkflowState workflowState;
    private Date approvedDate;
    private Date submittedToCroDate;
    private Date acceptedByCroDate;
    private String description;
    private Double estimatedCroScientists;
    private Double actualCroScientists;
    private Date croChemistAssignedDate;
    private String estimatedDuration;
    private Priority priority;
    private String coordinatedBy;

Comment: private String croLead;
    private Date agreedDueDate;
    private Date completionDate;
    private Date estimatedStartDate;
    private Date actualStartDate;
    private String croTrainingStatus;
    private String analyticalFileStatus;
    private Date lastNotebookReviewDate;
    private Category category;
    private Precedence precedence;
    private String literatureReferences;
    private String createdBy;
    private Date createdDate;
    private Set<Attachment> attachments = new HashSet<Attachment>(0);

Comment: private Set<Contact> contacts = new HashSet<Contact>(0);
    private Set<PfComment> pfComments = new HashSet<PfComment>(0);
    private List<CompoundSpecification> compoundSpecifications = new ArrayList<CompoundSpecification>(0);
    private String displayName;
    private boolean multiple;
   
    private Set <ProjectTable> projectTable = new HashSet<ProjectTable>(0);

Comment: public ProjectForm () { }
    
    public ProjectForm (String lnbWorkRequestId) {

        String username = "CRAW";//(principal != null ? principal.getName() : "CRAW");
        Date date = new Date();
        Workflow workflow = Workflow.getInstance();
        this.lnbWorkRequestId = lnbWorkRequestId;
        this.workflowState = workflow.getInitialState();
        this.submittedDate = date;
        this.createdBy = username;
        this.createdDate = date;
        if ( username != null ) {
            setSubmittedBy( username );
        }
    }

Comment: **@Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "PROJECT_FORM_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "PROJECT_FORM_SEQ", sequenceName = "PROJECT_FORM_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "PROJECT_FORM_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 15, scale = 0)
    @NotNull
    public long getProjectFormId() {
        return this.projectFormId;
    }

    public void setProjectFormId(long projectFormId) {
        this.projectFormId = projectFormId;
    }
    
    public void setMultiple(boolean multiple) {
  this.multiple = multiple;
 }**

Comment: You need to verify how you're doing your one-to many relationship mapping. "private Set<Contact> contacts = new HashSet<Contact>(0); " : Here you didn't configure any mapping properties.

Comment: How to configure any mapping properties here please suggest?

Comment: See my response in the Answers section. I have pasted sample code snippet in Answers section.

Answer (score 0):

### Example of a OneToMany relationship and inverse ManyToOne annotations

```
@Entity
public class ProjectForm ....
...
@Id
@Column(name="PF_ID")
private long projectFormId;
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy="projectForm", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL})
private Set<Contact> contacts = new HashSet<Contact>();
...


@Entity
public class Contact ...
...
@ManyToOne(cascade= {CascadeType.ALL} , fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="PROJECTFORM_CONTACT")
private ProjectForm projectForm;
...
```

Comment: Not getting it. Tried but still the same issue.

Comment: Provide the java source code of Contact entity class with mapping properties with ProjectForm entity class. Only mapping section paste it

Comment: **unable to paste it because so many notation "@" is used For this I am unable to paste it here. @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SOW_ID")
    public Sow getSow() {
        return this.sow;
    }**

Comment: any other way is there to paste the code snippet ??

Comment: Where mudid property is present? In which entity class. Is there any relationship established between ProjectForm entity class. If yes put it here how the relationship been established between them? In this Query: "left join pf.contacts c " + "WHERE pf.createdBy=:mudid " + "OR pf.modifiedBy=:mudid " + "OR c.mudid=:mudid ":  check the "mudid" is actually a DB column and entity class property.?

Comment: Is "mudid"  a property of Contact Entity class? How do you establish the relationship between  ProjectForm and  Contact entity class on both side?

Comment: Yes its present. The problem is same query is working fine in Jboss 4.2 but for 7.2 I am getting error. For both we are using same table and column.

Comment: **@Id
 @GeneratedValue(generator = "CONTACT_SEQ")
 @SequenceGenerator(name = "CONTACT_SEQ", sequenceName = "CONTACT_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
 @Column(name = "CONTACT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 15, scale = 0)
 @NotNull
 public long getContactId() {
  return this.contactId;
 }

 public void setContactId(long contactId) {
  this.contactId = contactId;
 }
 **

Comment: public class ProjectForm
... 
private Set<Contact> contacts = new HashSet<Contact>(0); 

How do you establish the relationship between ProjectForm and Contact ?

Comment: `@Column(name = "MUDID", nullable = false, length = 200)
 @NotNull
 @Length(max = 200)
 public String getMudid() {
  return this.mudid;
 }

 void setMudid(String mudid) {
  this.mudid = mudid;
 }

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn(name = "CONTACT_ROLE_ID", nullable=false)
 @NotNull
 public ContactRole getContactRole() {
  return this.contactRole;
 }

 void setContactRole(ContactRole contactRole) {
  this.contactRole = contactRole;
 }`    THE ABOVE SNIPPETS ARE FROM CONTACT ENTITY

Comment: `@Transient
    public Contact getCoordinatorContact () {
        return getContactByRole( ContactRole.getCoordinatorInstance() );
    }
    

    @Column(name = "COORDINATED_BY", length = 100)
    @Length(max = 100)
    public String getCoordinatedBy() {
        return this.coordinatedBy;
    }

    public void setCoordinatedBy(String mudid) {
        this.coordinatedBy = StringUtils.stripToNull( mudid );
        setContact( coordinatedBy, ContactRole.getCoordinatorInstance() );
    }`

Comment: Is there setter/getter methods present of "Set <contacts>" and mapping in   ProjectForm.java?

Comment: Have you  established the  mapping relationship  details in the setter/getter methods of "Set <contacts> = "  in  ProjectForm.java?  If yes, paste it only their relationship made.                                                Similarly,  I believe that you surely have established the relationship in Contact Entity class with  ProjectForm Entity class.  I want to see how you made the relationship in between? Paste it here only relationship mapping details.